# How to write an assert statement in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, testing

I want a quick check like `assert(route?.params?.array !== undefined)`.

The closest I've found is node's `assert` library. But I don't think that's useable out of the box with React-native. (If it is, I'd accept an answer showing me how!)

I would accept a `try catch` code where I can catch if array is undefined.

Right now I'm doing something like

```
try {
    route.params.array.length;
} catch(err) {
    console.log("ERR: looks like array is undefined.");
}
```

But I would like something less hacky. Also, any suggestions about how to do testing properly in React-Native are welcome.